# Pyspark Performance Tuning while merging multiple part files

Tags: performance, pyspark, schema, partition, merge-file

I am kind of new in spark and i have a requirement where i am required to read from different part folders and then merge them all together to create a single df based on a passed schema. it is something like this

```
/feed=abc -> contains multiple part folders based on date like below
/feed=abc/date=20221220
/feed=abc/date=20221221
.....
/feed=abc/date=20221231
```

Each part folder can have multiple part files. All the files are in parquet format but the schema across two different part folders may vary either in the number of cols or in datatype. So my approach is

1 - create an empty final_df based on the schema passed
2 - Iterate over the list of part folders using the below code

```
hadoop = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop
fs = hadoop.fs.FileSystem
conf = hadoop.conf.Configuration()
path = hadoop.fs.Path(inp_fl_loc)
    for f in fs.get(conf).listStatus(path):
        path2 = str(hadoop.fs.Path(str(f.getPath())))
        if(f.isDirectory()):
            path2= path2 + "/"
            print("the inp_path is ",str(path2))
            #splitting the individual name to get the corresponding partition col name and value
            temp_path = path2.split("/")[-2]
            part_col,part_val = temp_path.split("=")[0],temp_path.split("=")[1]
        elif('_' in path2.split("/")[-1]):
            continue

        #reading the file
        df = 

spark.read.format(inp_fl_frmt).option("mergeSchema","true").load(str(path2))

#other operation follows :-
```

3 - Once a particular part folder is read, comparing the schema of the read_df with that of the final_df and selecting only the req cols and if required typecasting the req col of the read_df based on the final_df schema. Note in this process i might have to type cast a sub-col within a struct type variable as well. For that i am actually expanding the struct variables into new cols, type casting them and then again converting them back in the original structure.
4 - Unioning the typecasted read_df with the final_df.
5 - Repeat steps 3-4 for all the part folders ultimately giving me the final final_df

The thing is in the presence of large data (in one of my feed i am reading 340 part folders totalling around 13000 files close to around 7GB in total) the job is running for a large amount of time (7hrs+ in the above case).
Since i am working on a shared cluster i dont have the exact details of the number of nodes and the number of cores and following the standard configuration used in our team...but seems like that is not enough. The above details are not yet handy but i am trying to get those but i am more concerned if any tuning is possible from the code perspective.
Few questions that i have in mind :-

- Since i am using the loop to read each part folder one by one i think the reading is happening serially rather than parallelizing the operation. Is it possible to read the different part folders parallely. I tried reduce operation but that isn't working properly.
- Post the union of read-df with the empty df i am caching the empty_df so that in the next union operation the empty_df is not recalculated. But that doesn't seem to help in perf. Shouldn't i cache the empty-df ?

Any help regarding this is much appreciated.

Comment: HNY. Why not read the manuals on parallel processing?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several considerations that impact the performance of your job:

- the simple Python `for` loop is **not** distributing the work evenly across nodes - you are losing the benefit of running a distributed engine like Spark by overloading only one of the workers
- your folder structure already seems quite nicely partitioned, so reading the data even with varying schemas shouldn't be that big of a problem
- selecting and casting the columns would make most sense only after you have read all the required files - before that, you are risking of building large `if-else` spaghetti to handle every possible case

A simple solution: have you tried reading in all of the desired folders, by passing a whole directory to the Spark?

In general, when you have varying schemas, then *sane* solution is to have a separate DataFrame for group of files with distinct *schema*, and then use function like [`unionByName`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.unionByName.html#pyspark-sql-dataframe-unionbyname) to combine them. You can pass `allowMissingColumn` to `True`, so that when for example DataFrame `A` doesn't have some columns of DataFrame `B`, after union, it will have a NULL values assigned there, instead of throwing an exception.

Try out any of the solutions, and let me know which one worked the best - always interested what works for people :)

Comment: "A simple solution: have you tried reading in all of the desired folders, by passing a whole directory to the Spark?" - yes. When i am trying to read the entire feed=abc folder rather than going one more level deep i am facing two types of issues
1) if the datatype of some common col is different in two different part folders the job is failing 
2) if datatypes are same for the common cols across diff part folders then the job is giving me a df having few cols but not all if there are other cols present specific to individual part folders.

Comment: You are absolutely correct in the point that i have a big if-else logic to handle diff scenarios for the type-casting part, since i am not sure which col can be present in which part-folder and it's datatype . But i didnt quite understand how can i read all the part folders at first and post that change the datatype of some col when i am not even sure which col the problem is ? Are you suggesting to use a map for reading the individual partfolders and then do the operation ? But if there are 300+ part folders then there will be 300+ dfs in the map output which will be memory intensive

Comment: Can threadpool be used to solve this. As far my idea goes when i create a threadpool then the main driver spawns multiple threads and each thread will have access to the sparkSession and executed the code. In my case, the ideal scenario will be where reading and processing of each part-folder as well as write into a temp location should be done by an individual thread. And once all the threads have completed the rest of the code will be just reading that temp location. Is this approach even possible ?